# Android app Twitter Login failed(not show webView login screen) if twitter app not installed

Tags: android, twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

**Edit 1**
I know this question is already asked but no one is answered stacktrace also not added into it so I asked again. 
If I install twitter app ant try to login then app will successfully login with twitter but if I un-install twitter app from mobile and then try to login into app then I received below error and failed to get login with twitter

**Failed to get request token**

I didn't seen any webView. after click on login with twitter button.

below is stack trace which I received

E/Twitter: Invalid json: Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings
    com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.SafeListAdapter$1.read(SafeListAdapter.java:45)
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.SafeMapAdapter$1.read(SafeMapAdapter.java:45)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773)
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException.parseApiError(TwitterApiException.java:110)
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException.readApiError(TwitterApiException.java:95)
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException.(TwitterApiException.java:43)
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.onResponse(Callback.java:42)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:213)
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.SafeListAdapter$1.read(SafeListAdapter.java:45) 
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.SafeMapAdapter$1.read(SafeMapAdapter.java:45) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773) 
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException.parseApiError(TwitterApiException.java:110) 
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException.readApiError(TwitterApiException.java:95) 
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException.(TwitterApiException.java:43) 
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.onResponse(Callback.java:42) 
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

E/Twitter: Failed to get request token
    com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: HTTP request failed, Status: 403
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.onResponse(Callback.java:42)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

E/Twitter: Authorization completed with an error
    com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Failed to get request token
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthController$1.failure(OAuthController.java:94)
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuth1aService$1.failure(OAuth1aService.java:191)
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.onResponse(Callback.java:42)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: I'm using Signin with Twitter via FirebaseUI on Android. I came across the same issue today. Have you found a solution?

Comment: No, I didn't found solution yet, I try to integrate Login using both Firebase and Twitter but no luck as of now, and also I tried different solutions like set call back URL and all but getting same issue.  Did you able to login using Twitter instead of Firebase UI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I got answer [here.](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/issues/108#issuecomment-397499851)

We need to set **twittersdk://** inside callback URL as described in link like below.

Step 1: go to your twitter app setting https://apps.twitter.com/ >> Tab settings >> Fill this text "twittersdk://" to your callback URL field( I found it in lib class)
Step 2: Save your update 
Step 3: check out your app again.

It worked just by setting **twittersdk://** as one callback URL, without appending anything.

Comment: I have multiple callback URLs before, does I need remove all and add only this. Currently it doesn't work for me, but I'm afraid of removing previous urls will affect iOS

Comment: try regenerating consumer key and consumer secret (if possible).

Comment: it works fine now, I forgot clicking "Update settings" button after adding new callback_url :D, thank you